# create modified list out of register stdout_lines output

Tags: ansible

In a playbook I have a task searching for disk candidates basing on LUN ID range of the disks in the system:

```
  - name: find disk candidates
    shell: lsscsi|grep -E '\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:1.\][[:space:]]+disk.+/dev/sd'|awk '{print $NF}'
    register: disk_devices
```

In next task I create disk partitions on the disks:

```
  - name: create partitions
    parted:
     device: "{{ item }}"
     number: "{{ partition_number }}"
     label: gpt
     state: present
    with_items:
      - "{{ disk_devices.stdout_lines }}"
```

Now I have problem to create volume group from the partitions created on the disks.

The disks list on disk_devices is output of this command:

```
$ lsscsi|grep -E '\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:1.\][[:space:]]+disk.+/dev/sd'|awk '{print $NF}'
/dev/sdc
/dev/sdd
/dev/sde
/dev/sdf
/dev/sdg
/dev/sdh
/dev/sdi
/dev/sdj
/dev/sdk
/dev/sdl
```

Ansible's *lvg* module requires comma separated list for the *pvs* attribute:

```
/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1,/dev/sdg1,/dev/sdh1,/dev/sdi1,/dev/sdj1,/dev/sdk1,/dev/sdl1
```

I did register new variable with task:

```
  - name: Auxiliary task
    shell:  echo {{ disk_devices.stdout_lines }}|sed s/$/1/|paste -sd, -
    register: disk_partitions
```

But when I debug disk_partitions I get:

```
TASK [Auxiliary task] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [l27.0.0.1] => {
    "msg": "Found [/dev/sdc, /dev/sdd, /dev/sde, /dev/sdf, /dev/sdg, /dev/sdh, /dev/sdi, /dev/sdj, /dev/sdk, /dev/sdl]1"
}
```

It is different from the output I get when run the shell command in the bash, which is:

```
/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1,/dev/sdg1,/dev/sdh1,/dev/sdi1,/dev/sdj1,/dev/sdk1,/dev/sdl1
```

How could I get such dynamic list of disk partitions for using it in `pvs` attribute in `lvg` module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a loop for Calculate disk partitions and the filter join to Join disk partitions to string

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: find disk candidates
      shell: lsscsi|grep -E '\[[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]\][[:space:]]+disk.+/dev/sd'|awk '{print $NF}'
      register: disk_devices

    - name: Calculate disk partitions
      vars:
        disk_entry: "{{ item }}1"
      set_fact:
        disk_partitions: "{{ disk_partitions | default([]) + [disk_entry] }}"
      loop: "{{ disk_devices.stdout_lines | list }}"

    - name: Join disk partitions to string
      set_fact:
        disk_partitions_pvs: "{{ disk_partitions | join(',') }}"

    - name: debug
      debug:
        msg: "{{ disk_partitions_pvs }}"

And the output:

TASK [debug] *************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "/dev/sda1,/dev/sdb1,/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you want to append partition number to each disk returned in `disk_devices.stdout_lines`. There is a `join` filter in Ansible, which  allows us to "join" the list elements with the character(s) of our choice. So something like below should do the job:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        pvs: "{{ disk_devices.stdout_lines|join('1,') }}1"
    - debug:
        var: pvs
```

Output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "pvs": "/dev/sdc1,/dev/sdd1,/dev/sde1,/dev/sdf1,/dev/sdg1,/dev/sdh1,/dev/sdi1,/dev/sdj1,/dev/sdk1,/dev/sdl1"
}
```

The other slightly longer way to do this, is to create a new variable which concatenates `1` to each element by looping on `stdout_lines`. Like so:

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_pvs: "{{ my_pvs | default([]) + [ item ~ '1' ] }}"
      loop: "{{ disk_devices.stdout_lines }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "PVs: {{ my_pvs | join(',') }}"
```